# C++ constructor, one for degrees, one for radians

Tags: c++, constructor

What would be the best practice in C++, to define two separate constructors, one having input in degrees whilst the other in radians?  The problem I'm having doing it the straight forward way is that the signature of both methods look the same to the compiler, even though the parameter names identify which is which, and the compiler flags a `re-declaration` error.  Is this possible to do without introducing another field?

I can do it using a single constructor by adding an additional bool parameter that would allow selecting which units are being passed, and using an if in the body.

Comment: Constructor for what? Is your class representing an `Angle`? You can make static functions: `fromRadians` and `fromDegrees`

Comment: Instead of using a flag, that is going to be opaque, either write two factory functions or, preferably, create types that correspond to the different units of measure and overload on them.

Comment: You would be surprised, but there are more than 2 representations of angle, so I would use enum not bool. And even if you need only 2 enum is more readable.

Comment: @Slava any flag will be a source of bugs in this case. It is almost a guarantee.

Comment: @AluanHaddad using `bool` would be much worse than `enum`.

Comment: @Slava indeed, but both are bad.

Comment: @AluanHaddad agree, named constructor much better.

Comment: Wasn't expecting the eager feedback, and thanks for the input.  L8 here atm, so I'll read the proposals in the morning.

Comment: @gone these arguments are fun. Cheers!

Comment: @gone Asking for _the best practice_ usually comes out being _too broad_. See the many different answers you got. How would you decide now what the _"best practice"_ actually is?

Answer (score 15):

Use the [named constructor idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-ctor-idiom). Make your constructor private, and pick whichever you prefer for the argument type, degrees or radians. Then make appropriately named static member functions which do the necessary conversion.

```
class Angle {
public:
    static Angle radians(double r) { return Angle(r); }
    static Angle degrees(double d) { return Angle(d / 180.0 * PI); }
private:
    double angle_in_radians;
    Angle(double r) :angle_in_radians(r) {}
};
```

Comment: Most probably radians would be preferable as almost all standard functions work with them.

Comment: @Slava: There are advantages to degrees though. Namely, that you can store a right angle, as well as many other commonly encountered angles(45, 30, 60, 180, 270), with exact precision.

Comment: This is a very solid answer. The only thing I dislike is that the factories are static class members. It would be more idiomatic to put them in a namespace as free functions. Think `std::make_shared`, or `std::for_each`. Another nitpick is that you are returning the result of another constructor instead of using C++11 delegating constructors.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: More idiomatic to whom? The named constructor idiom has been on Marshall Cline's C++FAQ for over 20 years, and now it's on the official isocpp website. Doesn't get any more idiomatic than that, when it comes to C++. And how can I use a delegating constructor in a static member function(or a free function, if I go with your suggestion)?

Comment: That's true you would need to use constructors, not factories to delegate. I misread part of your impl. That said, not to be disrespectful of tradition, but 20 years of C++ is not something that impresses me when the language designers, especially Stroustrup state over and over and over again how and why the old ways should be dropped. Just watch any talk he gave within the last 4 years, I have learned so much from them. Anyway, I define idiomatic based on the structure of the standard libraries, what lang designers say, and on [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines)

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Bjarne Stroustrup doesn't determine what is idiomatic C++ (at least not solely). C++ users do. That said, this is the front page of the FAQ I linked to: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq -- You may notice a familiar name near the top.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley touché, my friend. I wonder what Marshall Cline would say about this discussion. I don't just follow Stroustrup. I try to keep up with C++ in my spare time because it is such an interesting language but I don't write in it as often as I would like.

Comment: Anyway, I am going to upvote this answer because it most definitely solves the problem in a clean, unambiguous, and readable fashion. It will lead to maintainable code. I'd be curious to know what you think of my approach however.

Answer (score 6):

> What would be the best practice in C++, to define two separate constructors, one having input in degrees whilst the other in radians?

The best practice would be to have only a single constructor that clearly takes only one of them (most probably radians, since all the trigonometrical functions work with radians).

You should have additional functions to convert the values. One way is to use [user defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)<sup>1</sup>.

These are meant to give plain values a context with a particular unit to use.

---

I would go the following way:

```
constexpr long double operator"" _deg ( long double deg )
{
    return deg2rad(deg);
}

long double deg2rad(long double deg) {
    return deg*3.141592/180;
}

long double rad2deg(long double rad) {
    return (rad/3.141592)*180;
}

class Angle {
public:

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    Angle() : radians() {}
    /**
     * Takes the initial angle value as radians.
     */
    Angle(long double rad) : radians(rad) {}

    // Convenience setters and getters
    void rad(long double value) {
        radians = value;
    }
    long double rad() const {
        return radians;
    }
    void deg(long double value) {
        radians = deg2rad(value);
    }
    long double deg() const {
        return rad2deg(radians);
    }
private:
    long double radians; // Only use radians internally
};

int main() {
    Angle ang1(180_deg); // Initialize using the constexpr conversion
    long double deg = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter an angle value in degrees: " << std::flush;
    std::cin >> deg;
    Angle ang2(deg2rad(deg));

}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>
<sub>The examples from the documentation even have one for converting degrees to radians.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I suggest an approach such as

```
const auto PI = 22 / 7.0;

const struct Degrees {
    explicit constexpr Degrees(double value): value{value} {}
    const double value;
};
const struct Radians {
    explicit constexpr Radians(double value): value{value} {}
    const double value;
};

const struct Angle {
    constexpr Angle(Radians r) : radians{r} {}
    constexpr Angle(Degrees d) : Angle{Radians{180.0 * (d.value / PI)}} {}
    const Radians radians;
};

decltype(auto) operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Degrees& d) {
    return out << d.value << " degrees";
}
decltype(auto) operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Radians& r) {
    return out << r.value << " radians";
}
decltype(auto) operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Angle& a) {
    return out << "angle: " << a.radians;
}

int main() {
    auto d = Degrees{1};
    auto a1 = Angle{Radians{1.65}};
    auto a2 = Angle{Degrees{240}};
    std::cout << a1 << '\n' << "Press any key to continue...\n";
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Notice how we have made the constructors for `Radians` and `Degrees` explicit. This prevents them from being called implicitely, requiring that the user declare their intent.

Now in this case, implicit construction such as

```
auto a = Angle{1.65}; // won't compile due to ambiguity
```

would cause an ambiguity error, but that may not remain true over many iterations of API releases.

For example if we removed or changed the visibility of one of the `Angle` constructors, the code above would compile without error.

The `explicit` constructors for `Degrees` and `Radians` prevents this hazard and make the code clearer.

We can add user defined literals as syntactic sugar on top of these types to enable a more terse notation.

For example:

```
constexpr auto operator ""_deg(long double d) { return Degrees(d); }
```

and

```
constexpr auto operator ""_rad(long double r) { return Radians(r); }
```

enable

```
auto a = Angle{240.0_deg};
```

and

```
auto a = Angle{1.65_rad};
```

respectively

This works because of the enhanced constexpr facilities in recent versions of the language. Since we marked our constructors as compile time-evaluatable, they can be used as the types of literals. Note my literals are potentially truncating from `long double` to `double` and I have yet to learn why declaring them as `long double` is required at least in MSVC 19.11.25505.

**Update:**

After reading through the other answers, which I thoroughly enjoyed (thanks all), I realized that much more compile time evaluation was in order so I added a slightly revised implementation incorporating some of what I learned. It is also more lightweight than my previous version and doesn't use accessors.

The implementation above is the revised version.

Answer (score 1):

Varying Benjamin's approach:

```
class Angle
{
public:
    class Radian; // both with constructor accepting the value
    class Degree; // and a member to store it - ommitting internals

    Angle(Radian const& r);
    Angle(Degree const& d);
};

Angle(Angle::Degree(180));
Angle(Angle::Radian(4.7));
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use *disambiguation tags*.

```
constexpr struct radians_t {
    constexpr explicit radians_t() = default;
} radians;

constexpr struct degrees_t {
    constexpr explicit degrees_t() = default;
} degrees;
```

Then define your constructors:

```
foo(double a, radians_t);
foo(double a, degrees_t);
```

And invoke like so:

```
foo(90.0, degrees);
foo(3.14, radians);
```

While superficially similar to the "named factory" solution, disambiguation tags are compatible with things like perfect forwarding and placement new. For example:

```
auto p1 = new (buffer) foo(90.0, degrees);
auto p2 = std::make_unique<foo>(3.14, radians);
```

Comment: Doesn't this lead to the same ultimate problem as the Boolean flag though? I mean sure the names are great, but their is nothing that ties tag to the value, so it seems like an easy API call incorrectly.

Comment: @AluanHaddad It's better than the boolean flag because a) it's more explicit and b) the unit selection is made at compile time. Sure, I agree that having `radians` and `degrees` encapsulate the value is maybe preferable, but that answer has already been given, so I was just providing an alternative.

Comment: Fair enough, but I think that factories and types kind of cover good solutions. I appreciate the use of `constexpr`, its always interesting to see new applications of it, but I'd be hard pressed to recommend this approach is all.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I much prefer it to the named factory approach, because it allows you to call the constructor directly, which gives more flexibility (e.g. use with placement new/`emplace`/`in_place`). I would say it's second in my book to having actual types, but it's nice and quick and easy when you don't necessarily want to spend time implementing those classes.

Comment: That an excellent point! I had not considered that. However, given how lightweight the types are in my answer, 2 lines of implementation per unit, how would you compare the unit types approach to the _disambiguation tags_ approach. I'm honestly looking for feedback.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I prefer actual types encapsulating the values if possible. However, I would also like said types to be _well_ encapsulated, with appropriate conversions between units and support for arithmetic and all the bells and whistles you usually expect from such types. This is a bit more work than in your answer, but if you can take the time, I'd say it's certainly preferable! See Boost.Units for a very complete solution.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll check that out! I still have negative feelings (read bad dreams) about `std::relops` from back in college.

Answer (score 1):

I'll say at the beginning that this is a heavier approach, but you can make a rigorous separation of degrees and radians throughout your application by using opaque typedefs.  This would prevent accidental mixing of values with different units -- they become compile-time errors rather than run-time errors.  I have [an opaque typedef library](https://sourceforge.net/p/opaque-typedef/wiki/Home/) that makes it convenient to create numeric opaque typedefs and to express the operations allowed on them.

You could make separate degrees and radians types, with degrees convertible to radians, like this:

```
#include "opaque/numeric_typedef.hpp"

constexpr auto PI = 22 / 7.0;

struct degrees : opaque::numeric_typedef<double, degrees> {
  using base = opaque::numeric_typedef<double, degrees>;
  using base::base;
};

struct radians : opaque::numeric_typedef<double, radians> {
  using base = opaque::numeric_typedef<double, radians>;
  using base::base;
  constexpr radians(degrees d) : base(d.value/180.0 * PI) { }
};

class Angle {
public:
  Angle(radians r) : angle_in_radians(r) { }
private:
  radians angle_in_radians;
};

int main() {
  Angle a(degrees(90.0));
  Angle b(radians(1.23));
  Angle c(5.0); // compile error
}
```